# Remove Phone Numbers & Email Addresses in a string SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Table with Field "UserId" in Postgres

The List Contains a list of UserIds (comma separated) but also might contain email addresses and phone numbers .

**Example**

| ID | UserID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111,22222,+9199999999,xyz@yxz.com |
| 3 | 2222,3333,11,+887777777,abc@bca.com |

I want to remove all the phone-numbers and Email addresses and get the list of all userids comma separated in a new field.

**OUPUT**

| ID | UserID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111,22222 |
| 3 | 2222,3333,11 |

Also it will be better to have the query being optimised as it will be a part of a much complex query and should not not impact the performance .

Can someone suggest an ideal way to do it ?

Thanks

I have tried SUBSTRING , SPLITPART and Case Conditions based on it , but couldn't come out with a proper solution.

Comment: Soring foreign keys and aditional data as csv is very bad db design. You should rethink it

Answer (score 0):

Use the REGEXP_REPLACE function to remove phone numbers.

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = REGEXP_REPLACE(columnname, '(\+[0-9]{1,3}[- ]?)?[0-9]{10,}', '');
```

Use the REGEXP_REPLACE function to remove email addresses.

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = REGEXP_REPLACE(columnname, '[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}', '');
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  I think the leading and/or trailing comma will be still there

Comment: it doesn't work: https://dbfiddle.uk/xoY9rw03